# Is there a serious ambiguity in the definition of the cross-product of unit vectors?

Tags: symmetry, vectors, tensor-calculus, definition, torque

Consider a force **F** acting along the x-axis applied to a directed lever arm **L** parallel the y-axis, and with the conventional torque **T** parallel to the z-axis, with the three vectors a right-handed triad.  It is now very well known that a torque is a tensor not a vector. It is a three-dimensional structure that acts in the plane of F and L and has an axis (although nothing acts along that axis). But the tensor representation is mathematically complicated and physics has designed an artificial vector, the 'axial' vector,  which acts along that axis, with its arrow direction associated by convention with the twist of the torque. This is the axial vector representation of the torque **T**, and works very well.
An ambiguity arises when the axial vector is represented by unit vectors. Here, T**k** = FL(**i**x**j**).
The unit vectors, **i**, **j**, **k**, are normally understood as polar vectors but   **i**x**j**  is an axial vector and transforms differently from a polar unit vector, and is not equivalent to **k**.
In the tensor representation of torques using unit vectors, **i**, **j** and **k** are all polar vectors, there are no axial vectors, and there is no ambiguity or incoherence.
I am unable to make coherent sense of the cross-product using unit vectors. I am stuck. Normal cross-products work very well in physics so I sense intuitively that there must be an easy 'fix'.

Comment: *The unit vectors, **i**, **j**, **k**, are normally understood as polar vectors.* I think this is simply wrong when using Gibbs notation. They are used to represent both polar and axial vectors. I agree with you that this makes Gibbs notation ambiguous. However, if you know that a vector is a momentum vector, then you know it is polar; if you know it is an angular momentum vector you know it is axial; etc. The ambiguity is not a problem in practice for physicists.

Comment: Ghoster offers a possible fix. It is unrealistic to ask authors of undegraduate physics textbooks to exchange cross-products for pairs of dyads. A fix must accept ordinary cross products, and accept ixj = j; jxk = I etc., if possible. But  the latter, as they stand, violate symmetries. Unit axial vectors do behave like unit polar vectors in many cases, so for undergraduate calculations it does not matter if k is substituted for ixj. But there is a problem of rigour here. Can the equations by saved  by saying that k, in ixj, changes structure, but quantitatively and in direction it equals k?

Answer (score 1):

It is not ambiguous, but it is merely a convention, with the danger that mathematicians disagree with physicists on the definition of what it means for something to be right-handed. i.e. it is very possible to be using a physics right-handed coördinate system that happens to be mathematically left-handed. It takes some effort to stay in right-handed for both.

It is also unnatural, because spacetime is 3+1D, not 3D, such that the mathematically natural equations do not like this hack.

However, one really cannot help but enjoy the convenience of the cross product.

You might be confused with polar and axial vectors. That is ok. The unit vectors themselves are not supposed to be treated as axial vectors.

If you wish to never talk about axial vectors and cross products, you can. The mathematical machinery of geometric algebra generalises the idea behind cross products naturally to all dimensions. It does not send the product of two polar vectors to an axial vector. Instead, the bivector naturally encapsulates the rotation in the plane of the two vectors.

Comment: I like the last part of your comment. Would you agree that we are trivializing the subject too much in high school? Do you think we could teach it more properly?

Comment: @FlatterMann I do teach geometric algebra to teens, but it is difficult to fight against education systems inimical to progress. It is not sufficient that they see the magical answers that come about because GA can blast a fast path through old problems. Without sufficient practice problems for students, they would not retain the methods.

Comment: To begin understanding physics, first set aside the mathematics and interpret the concept within reality as you experience it rather than as mathematics models it.  What really is torque?  What does it do?  Does a torque wrench represent torque?  Does trying to open a tight bottle represent torque?  Know what it is in your experiences before getting inundated with equations.  If you have never experienced torque, then try to imagine what would be a good first experience of it.  Then interpret now how the imperfect model represents reality, rather than how reality represents the model.

Comment: @KenMellendorf I do agree that physics has to start with practical experience with nature, but that alone is not sufficient. Geometry didn't stop with Euclid and algebra didn't stop with Muhammad ibn Musa al-Khwarizmi. My high school days were almost 50 years ago and the concepts they were teaching in geometry and linear algebra were already insufficient for 1970s GR. My first insight that there was a world beyond what I had been taught about vectors came while reading MTW. I do agree with naturallyInconsistent that we are still teaching math as if it was Noon, 19th century.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I hear you. I wish I could start over from scratch with my basic math education because these days I am constantly fighting against primitive ideas that were taught to me 50 years ago and that work (barely) for undergrad physics. They don't work well for anything beyond that.

Comment: Im younger than you by decades but even I am giving up. There is too much stupid baggage leftover, always confusing me when Im trying to understand important physics. I can only clean up the notation and let the next generation take over. Im writing a series of textbooks that minimises the changes of notation, making choices suitable for QFT even at the beginning for classical mechanics, reducing the difficulty until beginners can understand, instead of throwing them to the sharks. But it is so much work to write, so little time to squeeze out of work days...

Comment: @KenMellendorf. Agreed. Especially in introductory physics the algebra ought to be an analogue of nature. Semantically, each term symbolises a natural property. Syntactically, their relations model natural relations. Newton's classical law of gravity is a good example. But  I agree with FlatterMan and NaturallyInconsistent in that anthropic convenience quickly muscles in, as in the axial vector representation of a torque. It is not a 'natural property' . It's physical Interpretation is a real mess.